# Does PureComponent work well with style array in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know that the following snippet gets optimized if styles are created by `Stylesheet.create()` and Child extends `PureComponent`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Child from './Child'
import styles from './stylesheets'

export default class Parent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child style={styles.x} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Does it also works with multiple styles? I'm afraid that `[]` literals prevent optimization.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Child from './Child'
import styles from './stylesheets'

export default class Parent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child style={[styles.x, styles.y]} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Or do I need to define combined style statically?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Child from './Child'
import styles from './stylesheets'

const childStyles = [styles.x, styles.y]

export default class Parent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Child style={childStyles} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @AshwinMothilal I know. My question is "Does `shouldComponentUpdate` check work well for hard-coded integer array?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that array literal spoils `PureComponent` optimization.